# VB6 MySQL Arabic

Tags: mysql, vb6

hi i have old mysql based system
it use mysql 5.0 and odbc 3.51 32 bit 
i sitting mysql and odbc to utf8
my vb app show arabic data truely
but in database it show as the following (äÙã ÇáãÚáæãÇÊ ÇáÅÏÇÑíÉ)
now  i try to update my app to .net but the data doesnt appear in arabic but appear encoded with this shape in app

what is this encode and how i can solve this problem?
note: when i use mysqlquery browser the data appear encoded and when use old version of sqlyog appear in arabic
thanks

```
Edit (Create Table Statement):
CREATE TABLE 'chairs' (
  'Cod' tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'Nam' varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  'Active' tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY ('Cod'),
  KEY 'Y_code' ('Cod')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Vb6: any Cody in vb6 show arabic data

Comment: Share the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` and your vb6 code also.

Comment: Probably in your database the data is not stored as utf8, but in a different character set, but the connection character set is correct (utf8), thus the displayed data is in Arabic.

Comment: Since it is VB6, it could be using an Arabic codepage.